# why puts() does not work with declared string?

Tags: c++, string, output, puts

```
char s[] = "asqa0";
string p;

cin >> p;

puts(s);
puts(p);
```

here, the last `puts(p);` gives me an error. `puts` works with `const char *p` where the pointed character cannot be changed but the pointer can be changed itself, then why does it work with a char array?

Comment: You are using puts which is C printing function with C++ std string. You can use std::cout or puts(p.c_str()) to make your code fixed.

Answer (score 2):

`puts()` expects a null-terminated `const char *` pointer as input.

`puts(s)` works because `s` is a `char[]` array that *decays* to a `char *` pointer, which is then implicitly convertible to a `const char *` pointer.

`puts(p)` does not work because `p` is a `std::string`, and there is no overload of `puts()` that takes a `std::string` as input.  You would need to use the `std::string::c_str()` method to get a suitable `const char *` pointer to the string data:

```
puts(p.c_str());
```

However, there is simply no good reason to ever use `puts()` in C++.  Use `std::cout` instead, which has overloaded `operator<<` for both `const char *` and `std::string` data:

```
cout << s;
cout << p;
```